# Help identifying BMX,frame, parts

Tags: frames

Yeah I recently bought a bike the crank set caught my eye and a couple other things there's stickers on it but I'm not sure which ones are real and which ones are not besides the obvious to any help on identifying the parts would be great and appreciated I think it might have multiple manufacture parts The crank arms have "boss" on it and the seatpost clamp has "GT" and the forks have "answr"The front and back wheels are 24-in[image]
[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I would google „boss bmx“.

Comment: Hi, welcome to bicycles.  It's unlikely that knowing who made the parts will help very much; is there a specific reason you need to know this?

Comment: I was looking around a little bit and it looks like to be like an '80s boss and some posts I can't remember where that bike frame is in the bike museum it's under something like '80s boss 24-in is that frame looks familiar to anyone

Answer (score 1):

I'd guess that none of those stickers are original - they are on weird angles, whereas bike frame decals are set to be readable from the side, or sometimes from above or below.  They never wrap around the frame like that.

Additionally, proper decals are often under a clear coat of paint, not stickers stuck on top of the paint.

On the positive side, the GT branded seatpost clamp looks authentic, as does the stem with its engraved logo.

The cranks look particularly stout as does the chainring and spider, so those parts  are representative of a decent bike.

I think with some cleanup, and new grips/cables/brakes you'd have a nice BMX bike for riding.